# How to count numbers with different digits smaller than a particular number?

Tags: algorithm, math, combinations, digits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [No of numbers less than a given number with no repeating digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13246275/no-of-numbers-less-than-a-given-number-with-no-repeating-digits)

The numbers smaller than 10 with *different digits* are: 9,8,7,....1. So there are **9 numbers**.

Similarly, numbers with *different digits* smaller than 100 are all except 11,22,33,44....,99, therefore **90 numbers** in total.
We can also compute this as (9*9)+9=90   (total combinations of 2 digit numbers + 1 digit numbers).

My problem is, if we are given a bound which is not a power of 10, like 123. Then how do we proceed?
There will be 90 numbers smaller than 100, and then the numbers 102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109 and 120. The rest all have one of the digits repeated. So in total there are 90 + 9 = **99 numbers**.

How can this count be computed without actually enumerating all the numbers?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: this here is the older question, so I'd say the other is a duplicate of this one. But thanks for the pointer.