# No of numbers less than a given number with no repeating digits

Tags: algorithm, math, combinations, digits

How can we find the number of numbers less than a given number with no repeating digits in it?

For example the number of such numbers less than 100 is 90. (11, 22, 33,44, 55,66,77,88,99 have repeating digits so are excluded).

Similarly for less than 1000, digits like 101, 110, 122, 202 etc have to be excluded.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation

Comment: Are you trying count these numbers or to enumerate them?

Comment: Can you add some context ? What's the max size of numbers ? What are the speed requirements ? Why not simply iterate and count ?

Comment: Does 001 have to be excluded as well?

Comment: The max size of number is 10^18. Iterating will be very slow.

Comment: @JanDvorak No not 001. 001 is same as 1 and it has no repeating digits.

Comment: The max is only 10^10, as no value wanted is larger than 9876543210. You can afford that.

Comment: Well the amount of numbers with no rep-digit is finite, so we could just build a look up table to get the result in O(1) :p

Comment: @JanDvorak Yes you are correct but I need something faster. Some solution using permutation and combination which can directly count the numbers.

Comment: As an alternative to my answer, you could pregenerate all ~4M numbers and use binary search. Not that it will be faster, though.

Comment: @MvG Well seen. But those question often come in batch, when half the class asks SO instead of searching a solution.

Comment: @JanDvorak, wrt your count of “~4M numbers”: it's actually 8877690, at 64 bit each, which amounts to about 68 MiB memory requirement. Generating and sorting that list might take about a second for optimized C++ code, and longer for interpreted languages and the likes.

Comment: How about using queues?  eg. From 1 you can push 10, 12,..19 to the queue and do the same from 2... and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to make it quicker. Notice that there is a correlation between the number of digits in the max number and the solution (number of numbers which I will call `NON`)

```
100 (3 digits) => NON = 10 * 9  
1000 (4 digits) => NON = 10 * 9 * 8  
10000 (5 digits) => NON = 10 * 9 * 8 * 7  
...  
10000000000 (11 digits) => NON = 10 * 9 * 8 * 7 * 6 * 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1
```

after one billion you're bound to repeat a digit

Answer (score 2):

You can consider two cases:

- numbers shorter than the limit
- numbers that that differ from the limit at some digit

The count of `d`-digit numbers is `9*9*8*... = 9*9!/(9-d)!` (the first digit may not be zero). The count of all numbers shorter than `d` is the count of 0-digit numbers + .. count of `d-1`-digit numbers. These sums may be precomputed (or even hard-coded).

The count of `d`-digit numbers with `f` first digits given is `(10-f)*...*(10-(d-1)) = (10-f)!/(10-d)!`. You can precomupte the factorials as well.

Pseudocode :

```
To precompute fac:
  - fac = int[10];
  - fac[0] = 1;
  - for i in 1..10:
    - fac[i] = fac[i-1] * i;

To precompute count_shorter:
  - cs = int[10];
  - cs[0] = 0;
  - cs[1] = 1; // if zero is allowed
  - for i in 1..10:
    - cs[i+1] = cs[i] + 9 * fac[9] / fac[10-i]
  - count_shorter = cs;

To determine the count of numbers smaller than d:
  - sl = strlen(d)
  - if sl > 10
    - return count_shorter[11]
  - else
    - sum = 0
    account for shorter numbers:
    - sum += count_shorter[sl]
    account for same-length numbers; len=count of digits shared with the limit:
    - sum += 9* fac[9] / fac[10-sl];
    - for every len in 1..{sl-1}:
      count the unused digits less than d[len]; credits to @MvG for noting:
      - first_opts = d[len]-1;
      - for every i in 0..{len-1}:
        - if d[i] < d[len]
          - first_opts -= 1;
      - sum += first_opts * fac[9-len] / fac[10-sl] 
  - return sum
```

Comment: Comparing your pseudocode with [my code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13249899/1468366), I see many similarities. You too split the number at position `len` into a head which you keep and a tail for which you count smaller numbers. But the `(d[len]-1)` term in your code ignores the fact that digits which already occurred in the head must not occur again in the tail. Compare that to the `firstHere` computation from my code to see the difference.

Comment: @MvG good point. The `(d[len]-1)` term is incorrect. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that does this. Comments in the code. The basic idea is that you iterate over the digits of the last counted number one at a time, and for every digit position you can count the numbers that have the same digits prior to that position but a smaller digit at that current position. The functions build upon one another, so the `cntSmaller` function at the very end is the one you'd actually call, and also the one with the most detailed comments. I've checked that this agrees with a brute-force implementation for all arguments up to 30000. I've done extensive comparisons against alternate implementations, so I'm fairly confident that this code is correct.

```py
from math import factorial

def take(n, r):
    """Count ways to choose r elements from a set of n without
    duplicates, taking order into account"""
    return factorial(n)/factorial(n - r)

def forLength(length, numDigits, numFirst):
    """Count ways to form numbers with length non-repeating digits
    that take their digits from a set of numDigits possible digits,
    with numFirst of these as possible choices for the first digit."""
    return numFirst * take(numDigits - 1, length - 1)

def noRepeated(digits, i):
    """Given a string of digits, recursively compute the digits for a
    number which is no larger than the input and has no repeated
    digits. Recursion starts at i=0."""
    if i == len(digits):
        return True
    while digits[i] in digits[:i] or not noRepeated(digits, i + 1):
        digits[i] -= 1
        for j in range(i + 1, len(digits)):
            digits[j] = 9
        if digits[i] < 0:
            digits[i] = 9
            return False
    return True

def lastCounted(n):
    """Compute the digits of the last number that is smaller than n
    and has no repeated digits."""
    digits = [int(i) for i in str(n - 1)]
    while not noRepeated(digits, 0):
        digits = [9]*(len(digits) - 1)
    while digits[0] == 0:
        digits = digits[1:]
    assert len(digits) == len(set(digits))
    return digits

def cntSmaller(n):
    if n < 2:
        return 0
    digits = lastCounted(n)
    cnt = 1 # the one from lastCounted is guaranteed to get counted
    l = len(digits)
    for i in range(1, l):
        # count all numbers with less digits
        # first digit non-zero, rest all other digits
        cnt += forLength(i, 10, 9)
    firstDigits = set(range(10))
    for i, d in enumerate(digits):
        # count numbers which are equal to lastCounted up to position
        # i but have a smaller digit at position i
        firstHere = firstDigits & set(range(d)) # smaller but not duplicate
        if i == 0: # this is the first digit
            firstHere.discard(0) # must not start with a zero
        cnt += forLength(l - i, 10 - i, len(firstHere))
        firstDigits.discard(d)
    return cnt
```

*Edit:* `cntSmaller(9876543211)` returns 8877690 which is the maximum number of numbers you can form with non-repeating digits. The fact that this is more than 10!=3628800 had me confused for a while, but this is correct: when you consider your sequences padded to length 10, then sequences of leading zeros are allowed in addition to a zero somewhere in the number. This increases the count above that of the pure permutations.